# Is this tense usage correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> However, this has the unfortunate side effect of causing people to be unwilling to engage in side-reflection in the first place. I personally had fell victim to this line of thinking in the past.

I not sure whether it's "had fell" or "had fallen", or even just "fell". Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP is incorrect, but the correction depends on what you're trying to say.
"I personally had fallen victim...". Once in the past.
"I personally fell victim...".  Once recently (doesn't really fit).
"I personally have fallen victim..." More than once in the past.

Given that "it" is a line of thinking, odds are you want the last one, as Kevin's answer suggests.

Comment: It looks to me like the author originally wrote "fell" then decided to change it to "had fallen" but missed changing "fell" to "fallen".

Answer (score 1):

I personally **have fallen** victim to this line of thinking in the past.